# How to print document from com.lowagie.text.Document

Tags: java, pdf, primefaces, printing

I'm trying to print a Primefaces dataTable with a button at the top of the datatable.  I started with the  functionality, but I only end up with the rows currently displayed on the page being printed (which I have learned is the expected behavior).  I then had what I thought at the time to be a great idea.  I would use a postProcessor on the Create PDF functionality, send the PDF to the printer, and then kill the process before the user is prompted to save the file.

Now I'm stuck.  I can't figure out how to go from com.lowagie.text.Document (which is what I have access to in the postProcessor method) to being able to actually send that PDF to the printer.  If I could find a cleaner way that just prints the entire dataTable, that would be amazing.  Unfortunately, I suspect that isn't going to happen, as I've been looking for such a solution for two days with no luck.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409645/create-a-pdf-file-in-memory/26412278#26412278

Comment: I appreciate the attempt meyquel, but that link doesn't address what I'm trying to figure out how to do:  send a printjob to a printer with the entire dataTable being printed, or send a printjob to a printer starting with a com.lowagie.text.Document.  Are you suggesting that is _part_ of what I need?

Comment: using p:media component you can print the pdf document, but you must build the pdf with the data in your table.

Comment: also try with p:printer component

Comment: A com.lowagie.text.Document is a wrapper for a document creator. If you only have that object, you're lost.